# 64bit deployment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, deployment, 64-bit

I would like to start making my application's 64bit, however, I am not sure on the changes I should make on my sln and vsproj files. What changes should I make to my sln and vsproj to make them 64bit?

On the same note, are there changes to the default sln or project file that are good for game development? I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Probably to run 64bit applications you need to have a 64 bit processor, so I guess you should compile them on a 64 bit processor.

Comment: you can build 64-bit apps on a 32-bit system, but you can't run them though.

Comment: Do bear in mind that unless you need the large address space, there are significant disadvantages to 64bit apps, and few advantages.

Comment: What are the "significant disadvantages to 64bit apps, and few advantages"?

Comment: 64bit does not have significant disadvantages. Many apps actually run a little faster because of the extra registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what was said before, make sure you understand why you need 64-bit support. In most cases you won't need access to larger memory allocations. Also, be aware that there will be x86/x64 P/Invoke compatibility problems (if you plan on using third-party unmanaged assemblies - in case you are working with managed C++).

For more information, read what [Scott Hanselman has to say about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx). Also, just as a sidenote, I would recommend reading [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravseth/archive/2006/03/07/545104.aspx) that explains some of the migration ideas.

Answer (score 4):

From the VS menu select `Build`|`Configuration Manager`.

On the Configuration Manager dialog, open the `Platform` drop down and select `<New...>`.

On the New Project Platform dialog select `x64` as your platform and click Ok.

Comment: By the way, one should note that the popular Visual Studio 2010 Express does not come with a 64-bit compiler.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `x64 solution platform`:

```
Build -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform -> New -> New platform = x64
```

if you don't see "x64" make sure you installed it in Visual Studio installer

then just select "x64" as `active solution platform` and build